# The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `-A` as a global option: celery -A celeryapp worker <...>

Tags: celery

./celery.sh                                                                              2 ⨯
You are using `-A` as an option of the worker sub-command:
celery worker -A celeryapp <...>

The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `-A` as a global option:
celery -A celeryapp worker <...>
Usage: celery worker [OPTIONS]
Try 'celery worker --help' for help.

Error: no such option: -A

Comment: So did you try `celery worker --help` for help?

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in the release notes (breaking changes) [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/history/whatsnew-5.0.html#step-1-adjust-your-command-line-invocation):

> The global options can no longer be positioned after the sub-command.
> Instead, they must be positioned as an option for the celery command

That means that you need to change from:

```
celery worker -A celeryapp <...>
```

to

```
celery -A celeryapp worker <...>
```

Comment: @rajkumar did it help you?

Comment: yea, I assumed you upgraded from 4.x to 5.x (by your question's title)

Comment: I came up with a similar issue when deploying to Heroku. Although I set the command as ```celery -A tasks worker```, but the above error message still occurred.

I posted a question here but no one helped...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469023/flask-celery-error-using-correct-command-but-still-error-you-are-using-a

Answer (score 1):

Is your first argument to Celery being the same as your file name?

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
```

I changed [tasks] same as my filename and run the command again, then it works.

```
celery -A myfilename worker
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else gets stuck here, I ran into this issue running celery using supervisor. Turned out I needed to clear the config cache on supervisor, see detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76251859/4028977).