# Flask - Celery Error: Using correct command but still Error "You are using `-A` as an option of the worker sub-command"

Tags: flask, heroku, celery

I spent a whole day on investigating this issue but can't figure it out. Although I followed the correct command as the Celery docs said: `celery -A tasks worker -l info`
But I still received an error saying that

```
You are using `-A` as an option of the worker sub-command:
celery worker -A celeryapp <...>

The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `-A` as a global option:
celery -A celeryapp worker <...>
```

In my Dockerfile for Celery, my command to execute Celery was:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["celery", "-A", "tasks", "worker", "-l", "info"]
```

In the Heroku Resource, it still shows the expected command:
[image]
But then when the Heroku is building, I've received this error

```
2021-10-06T15:33:34.586677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-10-06T15:33:34.937996+00:00 heroku[celery_worker.1]: Starting process with command `celery -A tasks worker -l info`
2021-10-06T15:33:35.568289+00:00 heroku[celery_worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-06T15:33:35.839353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-06T15:33:35.598861+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-06 15:33:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-10-06T15:33:35.599401+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-06 15:33:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:21157 (4)
2021-10-06T15:33:35.599471+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-06 15:33:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-10-06T15:33:35.604608+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-06 15:33:35 +0000] [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
2021-10-06T15:33:43.827079+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: You are using `-A` as an option of the worker sub-command:
2021-10-06T15:33:43.827086+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: celery worker -A celeryapp <...>
2021-10-06T15:33:43.827086+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: 
2021-10-06T15:33:43.827093+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `-A` as a global option:
2021-10-06T15:33:43.827093+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: celery -A celeryapp worker <...>
2021-10-06T15:33:43.830304+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: Usage: celery worker [OPTIONS]
2021-10-06T15:33:43.830306+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: Try 'celery worker --help' for help.
2021-10-06T15:33:43.830307+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: 
2021-10-06T15:33:43.831352+00:00 app[celery_worker.1]: Error: no such option: -A
```

Did I make something wrong or missing something in the configuration?

I'd be very glad to get your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you share the entire `Dockerfile`?

Comment: can you also confirm the version of Celery you have installed

Answer (score 0):

I got stumped on this working on an older stack I hadn't touched in several years.

In my case, I was running celery using supervisor, and I needed to run two supervisor commands after updating the celery command in my `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/appname-celery.conf` file.

The commands are described in [this documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps#step-2-adding-a-program), and are as follows:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

*THEN*

```
sudo supervisorctl restart appname-celery
```

I was able to test that my supervisor config updates for celery were not getting picked up by making the command line invalid, adding some random chars to the expected location of celery.

Another way I knew something was wrong was to run the "correct" command from the command line in the correct virtual env.  Doing that, I could see celery started up as expected.

It took some digging to get to the above DO walk through. tldr; it wasn't celery, but rather the cached configuration used by supervisor, which was running celery.